# cant change a symbol in every row from indexes list in Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

`indexes = [i for i in range(len(X_train['Total day minutes'])) if ',' in X_train['Total day minutes'][i]]`

**[100,196,232,249,288,351 and so on] - indexes**

**X_train.loc[indexes, 'Total day minutes'].replace(',', '.') - the values that i changed and they are correct now**

`X_train.loc[indexes, 'Total day minutes'] = X_train.loc[indexes, 'Total day minutes'].replace(',', '.')` *this doesnt work*

X_train.loc[indexes, 'Total day minutes']

```
100     226,7

196      97,5

232     168,4

249     198,3

288     252,4

351     186,1
```

but, `','`must be a `'.'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regex=True`:

```
X_train.loc[indexes, 'Total day minutes'] = X_train.loc[indexes, 'Total day minutes'].replace(',', '.', regex=True)
```

**OR:**

Use `.str.replace`:

```
X_train.loc[indexes, 'Total day minutes'] = X_train.loc[indexes, 'Total day minutes'].str.replace(',', '.')
```